# Bash one-liner to atomically create a file if it doesn't exist

Tags: bash, files

I want a Bash one-liner that atomically creates a file if it doesn't exist. That means essentially "if file doesn't exist, create it" but ensuring that no one else manages to create the file in the small space between doing the if and creating the file.

Comment: Sorry, I read 'atomically' as 'automatically.' I deleted my answer.

Comment: Did you see this; [atomic create file if not exists from bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13828544/1207760)?

Answer (score 8):

[Stealing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/147520) from various comments and links to [SO]. It seems there is a [POSIX compliant method](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_02) that doesn't involve `mkdir` as I mentioned in my original answer below

```
set -o noclobber # or set -C
{ > file ; } &> /dev/null
```

This redirect to *file* returns 0 or fails and returns non-zero if the file already exists.

---

Original answer

You'll have to use `mkdir` - that's atomic, either the directory gets created and you can continue or it doesn't created so you take appropriate action.

Of course, `mkdir` doesn't create a file but once you know you have exclusive access to the directory then you can make the file you want in it.

As to a one liner - I'll leave that up to you. Personally I'd write it over a few lines, as that'll be more maintainable.

Comment: But noclobber from http://stackoverflow.com/q/13828544/1207760 is more what OP wants.

Comment: Noclobber is, in general, a good answer. But it doesn't work for ksh88.

Comment: @JohnWiersba but the question is about bash.

Comment: @womble yes but the answer mentions POSIX which someone might take to mean that the answer applies to other shells.  Ksh88 is still the standard shell on some servers.

Comment: Does this technique also work for bash in standard (non-posix) mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. The `ln` provides the test-and-set functionality.

```
touch lock.$$.tmp
if ln lock.$$.tmp lock.dat 2>/dev/null
then
    echo "File is mine"
else
    echo "Test and set failed"
fi
rm -f lock.$$.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it file or directory? If file, you can use simple command touch - if file exists, it just modify last access time. If file doesn't exists, is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the filename, you can delegate this task to a utility, for example mktemp

```
Create a temporary file or directory, safely, and print its name.
TEMPLATE must contain at least 3 consecutive `X's in last component.
If TEMPLATE is not spec‐ified, use tmp.XXXXXXXXXX, and --tmpdir is 
implied.  Files are created u+rw, and directories u+rwx, minus umask
restrictions.
```

Invocation:

```
filename=$(mktemp)
```